# how can customize whereBetween in eloquent laravel when one of is null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my code - when $from or $to is null.i,m want this query convert >= or <= . how can i fixed problem with best optimize code :

```
$from=now()->subDays(1);
$to=now();
return Model::whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])->get();
```

Comment: now() would never been null

Answer (score 0):

You can not leave those variable null,
Altough you can use an if condation to cover a situation when $to or $from became null

for example

```php
if($to === null)
    Model::where('created_at','>=', $from)->get();
else
    Model::where('created_at','<=', $to)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case $from or $to equals null, you can use laravel's when method:

```
Model::when($from, function ($q) {
    $q->where('created_at','<=', $from)
})->get();
```